# How can I avoid Gutenberg blocks styles be written inline?

Tags: css, wordpress, performance, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm currently using the new block registration way, with *block.json* files.

My issue is that, if I add a style sheet, like:

```
"style": [ "file:./overlapping-columns.css", "overlapping-columns-style" ],
```

In the front-end, styles will be written inline instead of loading the *overlapping-columns.css* file. Why? Is there a way to make WordPress load them as a file? In the documentation, it's written that it should load as a file, and lazily (only when the block is shown on the page).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I understand, the conditional loading depends a little bit on what type of theme you are using.

If it's a block-based/FSE theme, the block CSS content will be conditionally loaded by default (I have tested this in a limited manner).

If it's a classic theme (uses PHP templates), you will need to add (sounds like you have already), the following to your theme.

```
add_filter( 'should_load_separate_core_block_assets', '__return_true' );
```

That filter is applied to the entire installation, and you would not need to add it to every block.

By default (in block themes) and classic themes that have the `should_load_separate_core_block_assets` filter enabled, WordPress will also inline the blocks' CSS content, described more in [this blog post](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/07/01/block-styles-loading-enhancements-in-wordpress-5-8/).

If you wish to load the block CSS as a file, use the following filter:

```
add_filter( 'styles_inline_size_limit', '__return_zero' );
```

(there is other WordPress CSS that is loaded on every page)).

Comment: No variation of these filters worked to prevent inline styles for me.

Comment: It works, but the CSS file created is inserted along with the scripts before the closing </body> tag, instead it should go in <head>.